# How to integrate ABAC in a Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, abac

Spring Security offers means for authorization like annotations (`@PreAuthorize`) and security-specific SpEL expression like `hasRole`. In principle this expression language could be extended to support ABAC, however that wouldn't really solve the architectural problem *where to do it*.

The application architecture is inspired by the [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) (which is in turn inspired by Hexagonal Architecture and the Onion Architecture). The basic building blocks look like this:

- *Adapter*: connects to the outside world, e. g. HTTP endpoints
- *Application services*: transforms to and from DTOs, provide transactions, perform **authorization**
- *Domain*: describes business data, rules and behaviours

From my point of view the application layer is the only suitable layer to perform authorization. It wouldn't fit into the adapter layer, because there could be multiple adapters for a single application service, so that the authorization would have to be repeated in several places. It wouldn't obviously fit into the domain, because it is a technical aspect that shouldn't be part of the domain logic.

A typical application service method gets some more or less "raw" parameters from the client, converts it and delegate the execution to the domain:

```
@Transactional
class MyApplicationService {
    fun cancelOrder(id: Long) {
        val orderId = OrderId(orderId)
        val order = orderRepository.findById(orderId)
        order.cancel()
    }
}
```

In order to be able to perform attribute-based access control (ABAC), the order object must be loaded before, so that the attributes can be extracted in the first place. That does also mean that an annotation like `@PreAuthorize` above the `cancelOrder` function wouldn't work, because the order object wouldn't be available there (SpEL would be able to reference function parameters, but the order is not passed as parameter!).

The only remaining possibility, that I can think of, is to call an authorization function explicitly before proceeding with business logic:

```
    fun cancelOrder(id: Long, principal: Principal) {
        val orderId = OrderId(id)
        val order = orderRepository.findById(orderId)
        checkPolicy(principal, order, Context.Complaint) // ?
        order.cancel()
    }
```

What concrete ABAC server (like OPA, AuthzForce, etc.) is not yet decided, but the solution at this level should be independent from it.

Is there a common approach for what I outlined as `checkPolicy`? Is there a typical "Spring approach" to integrate an external policy decision point? Or is there a fundamentally better solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1 - If you can modify the Order class:**

You may apply `@PreAuthorize` on the `Order#cancel()` method directly, this way you can do like the `checkPolicy` and access the `order` object (with `#this`):

```kotlin
class Order {
 //...
 @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#this, T(fully.qualified.Context).Complaint)")
 fun cancel() {...}
}
```

*If your `Context.Complaint` constant is a String, maybe it's more readable to put the string value (e.g. `'complaint'` ?) instead of `T(...Context).Complaint` in the Spel expression above.*

**Option 2 - If you cannot modify the Order class:**

You may use the Proxy pattern, i.e. wrap the call to `order.cancel` in a intermediate class/function and put the annotation on it:

```kotlin
@Transactional
class MyApplicationService {
 fun cancelOrder(id: Long, principal: Principal) {
  val orderId = OrderId(id)
  // Proxy pattern - new intermediary class 
  val order = OrderSecProxy(orderRepository.findById(orderId))
  order.cancel()
 }
}

class OrderSecProxy(val order: Order) {
 @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#this.order, T(fully.qualified.Context).Complaint)")
 fun cancel() {
  order.cancel()
 }
}
```

Then you have to implement a custom [PermissionEvaluator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/PermissionEvaluator.html) (Spring Security):

```kotlin
class AbacPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
     log.info("check permission '{}' for user '{}' for target '{}'", permission, authentication.getPrincipal(), targetDomainObject)
     var principal = authentication.getPrincipal()
     // Make the authorization request to the PDP with subject attributes from principal, action attribute from permission and resource attributes from targetDomainObject
     // ...
     // return true if PDP's decision is Permit, else false.
    }
}
```

[More info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#method-security-expressions).

So you should get the `order` object from the `targetDomainObject` argument. However, it would be more generic (ABAC style) - less business-specific - to use a Map of attributes instead, by changing the `@PreAuthorize` expression as follows:

*I assume the Order class has at least some `id` attribute but you can have other attributes.*

In case of option 1:

```kotlin
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(T(java.util.Map).of('resource-id', #this.id), T(fully.qualified.Context).Complaint)")
```

In case of option 2:

```kotlin
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(T(java.util.Map).of('resource-id', #this.order.id), T(fully.qualified.Context).Complaint)")
```

Last, configure the PermissionEvaluator in your application context:

```xml
<bean id="abacPermEvaluator" class="fully.qualified.AbacPermissionEvaluator">
    <!-- properties -->
</bean>

<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
 <security:expression-handler>
  <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="abacPermEvaluator"/>
    <!-- other properties like permissionCacheOptimizer-->
  </bean>
 </security:expression-handler>
</security:global-method-security>
```

You can do the same configuration with annotations as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however I see the problem that the Order class cannot carry the security annotation because it is not managed by Spring and I'd prefer to perform security checks outside of the domain layer in the application layer.

Comment: OK I edited my answer to show the alternative when the Order class cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks again. Option 2 wouldn't work, because the annotated method `secured_cancelOrder` would be called on the same instance as `cancelOrder` what means that it [wouldn't go through the proxy object](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) in therefore the annotation wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: I see, my bad.. If we move the annotated method to a separate class like in the Proxy design pattern, would that work? See my updated answer for example.